# SNMP, query perfomance

Tags: snmp

I have a router with SNMP and I'm writing a program, which gets traffic statistics it and display them in a graph.

MIB branch is `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2` (network interfaces). Query to this MIB results in 306 lines of OIDs.
I need these subtrees: `ifOperStatus` (8), `ifInOctets`/`ifOutOctets` (10/16), `ifInErrors`/`ifOutErrors` (14/20) subtrees.

I assume, that I would do the query every second.

Question - is it better to get all 306 lines in one query, or 5 separate queries for each subtree (each of which returns approx 17 lines) ?

Comment: What is your definition of `better` here ?

Comment: I dont know - speed and lower router cpu usage maybe? I dont want to halt router with too many queries in second.

Comment: 306 requests every second is almost certainly too often to be practical. Why would you do it so often? It may cause performance issues on the agent. I've never seen anyone need the data that fast, why not every 15 minutes?

Comment: No, its one query (GetNext) and its returns 306 lines.

Comment: It almost certainly does not. Did you snoop the network traffic? "snmpwalk" does a series of get-next requests to give you the whole table. If you use "get-bulk" instead, you can get multiple rows per query.

Answer (score 0):

From snmp-manager perspective, can you simply measure the various walk approaches e.g. on Linux here is trivial example with `time` command using [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) walks?

```
# time snmpwalk -v 2c -c  public    172.27.7.110 SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: Foo

real    0m0.036s
user    0m0.027s
sys     0m0.004s
```

For the CPU utilization on the agent side: 
    I assume you have tools to measure CPU usage etc.   etc

Comment: I do not know about this commands. Would try.
CPU utilization shows on router wb-interface.